# Placing Short (Red) / Long (Green) Triangle Labels in Proper Location in RSI Type Chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to place newly created long (L) green triangleup and short (S) green triangledown labels in RSI type chart between values of 30 & 70. This is the code I'm using at the moment with pine-script v5.

```
plotshape(qqeLong, title="QQE long", text="L", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(0,255,0,20), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(qqeShort, title="QQE short", text="S", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.rgb(255,0,0,20), size=size.tiny)
```

The triangles are printing on the RSI chart relative to the closing prices of crypto. So say BTC us now at $47,200 then triangle is plotting in y-position value of ~47200 instead of ~50 in custom RSI chart.

This is a [screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J815q.jpg) result using VET-USDT pair where triangles show in the ~0's range.

Help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scale, you are using the location of the `plotshape` above the bar `location=location.abovebar` this is similar to High price (0.8739 not 30 or 70), which would be at a different scale from `0` to `100` of the RSI. Thus, you wish use 30 and 70 instead with `location.absolute`. [See documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Plotting_shapes_chars_and_arrows.html)

```
plotshape(condition?70:na, title="QQE long", text="L", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(0,255,0,20), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(condition?30:na, title="QQE short", text="S", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(255,0,0,20), size=size.tiny)
```

Comment: Thanks Alfredo. This works!

Comment: I've also had some friendly person in asia answer it in telegram with below code in order to plot 'shapes' when lines intersect each other ||| 

plotshape(qqeLong ? FastAtrRsiTL : na , title="QQE long", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.diamond, location=location.absolute, color=color.rgb(0,255,0,20), size=size.tiny)